# Pasting $\LaTeX$ into a Mathematica notebook

Tags: notebooks, latex

I have read that $\LaTeX$ source [can be directly pasted into a Mathematica notebook](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/LaTeX.html). However, I have been unsuccessful in this regard. An example of the errors received are:

```
$\frac{1}{2}$
Syntax::sntxb: Expression cannot begin with "$ frac{1}{2}$".
Syntax::tsntxi: "$ frac" is incomplete; more input is needed.
Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
```

This is not remediated by removal of the `$` signs, placement of two `$` signs (`$$`), or use of other $\LaTeX$ math mode delimiters (e.g., `\[ \]`, `\begin{displaymath}\end{displaymath}`, `\begin{equation}\end{equation}`, etc). I do not wish to import an entire `.tex` file as I merely want to pass a few select equations. Please advise as to my error. Thank you.

**Edit:** I am using Mathematica 8.0.1.0.

Comment: Are you prompted whether you want to paste literal text or the corresponding typeset expression when you try to paste? Also, what version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I am using Mathematica version 8 (see edited post). I receive no prompts when I paste -- the $TeX$ markup is simply pasted directly into a cell in the notebook. Thank you.

Comment: I just learned that the prompt is controlled via GlobalOptions > MessageOptions > TeXPasteWarning in the Options Inspector which can be found under Edit > Preferences > Advanced. Yours may be set to False?

Comment: Thanks for looking into that and letting me know. Despite empirical evidence to the contrary, the `TexPasteWarning` parameter was set to True. Rebooting Mathematica did not enable prompting either.

Comment: @Andy please add that valuable information to your answer.

Comment: I am using 8.0.4 and it only worked when pasting
`$\frac {1} {2}$` and then with TeXPasteWarning enabled the dialog gives me option of accepting this format without further warnings.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm prompted by Mathematica when pasting (using 8.0.4) so I don't have this issue. The following seems to do the trick though..

```
ToExpression["\\frac{1}{2}", TeXForm]
```

I would expect others might have more illuminating responses to this.

**EDIT:**

The prompt I referred to  is controlled via GlobalOptions > MessageOptions > TeXPasteWarning in the Options Inspector which can be found under Edit > Preferences > Advanced. If this is set to `False` you won't get prompted as to how you would like to paste the input.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thank you very much. I suppose I can try rebooting and see if Mathematica starts issuing prompts.

Comment: The strings must contain double backslashes, which can be problematic when copying from sources. I have not found a convenient, automatic way to double the backslashes once inside MMA, because MMA interprets single backslashes as escaping the following character. In "\frac{1}{2}", the "\f" is interpreted as a line feed. I suppose `StringReplace` could be brought to bear, but it would take considerable work to make a robust backslash-doubling transform.

Comment: I'm running version 12, and TeXPasteWarning is true, but it still doesn't work for me, even if I go in and double the backslashes manually before copy/pasting

Answer (score 5):

I find pasting `$\frac{1}{2}$` works but pasting `\frac{1}{2}` does not. So the dollar signs seems necessary, although I realize that doesn't fix your problem it may be a useful hint to other users.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume I have the following $\LaTeX$ expression that I want to include in a Mathematica notebook

```
$\frac{d P(r)}{d r}=-\frac{G M \rho}{r^2}$
```

If I copy the expression, including the `$...$` (which are essential for Mathematica to recognize $\LaTeX$) and paste it in a Mathematica notebook, the following dialog box appears

[image]

And after clicking the button "yes", the following expression appears in the notebook (using Mathematica 12.1), as described in the documentation

[image]

The related issue of converting $\LaTeX$ into Mathematica input form is discussed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132862/41148).

---

**EDIT for Mathematica 12.2**

Mathematica 12.2 in December 2020 [introduced](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html) a new menu "Inline TeX Input" to write $\TeX$ or $\LaTeX$ input directly. Selecting the option from the Insert menu (or typing Ctrl+4)

[image]

Produces the following box, where one can type $\LaTeX$ directly

[image]

Clicking away from the box converts the $\LaTeX$ into Mathematica input

[image]

Comment: Hi divenex i do not what version of Mathematica you use but i just download a version trial 12.2.0 (the wesite of Mathematica is horrrible it is totally a mess) and I try paste formulas from MAthpix into latex for use as standar form and it is not work properly .I do not understood how mathematica do not check properly a program before to sell it , and whats mean clicling away???

Comment: @capea it seems your problem may be with mathpix & learning to use Mathematica in itself. “Clicking away” means exactly that, clicking out of the input field that is parses the latex input. At any rate, this is a new feature, and such issues may be expected with something just added to a program with such widely varied functionality.

Comment: Thanks CA trevillan , 
if you see the questions of other users you realize that the problem is not the user's I try only to help , anyway MAthematica it is a great progam