# Problem with LaTeX format

Tags: formatting, latex

I am trying to write the following function via latex

\begin{equation}
u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{2}+(t-x) ,\quad  0<x<t  \\
 xt-\frac{t^2}{2}+sin(x-t),\quad x>t>0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and gives a result
[image]

What do I have to do to fix the format?

Comment: Can you explain how this is linked to Mathematica and, if it is, can you give the MMA code you are using?

Comment: @MarcoB of course. I am writing a Mathematica notebook where I solve a PDE. First I want to write the mathematical solution and then the Mathematica code that gives us the 3D-PLOT. ```u(x,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{2}+(t-x) ,\quad  0<x<t  \\
 xt-\frac{t^2}{2}+sin(x-t),\quad x>t>0 
\end{cases}.``` and this is the code I have written in my notebook

Comment: Mathematica (13.2) doesn't seem to recognize the array syntax (even using double backslashes as per link).  However for more simple expressions, it does.  See this post:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/pasting-latex-into-a-mathematica-notebook#:~:text=Mathematica%2012.2%20in%20December%202020%20introduced%20a%20new,L%20A%20T%20E%20X%20into%20Mathematica%20input

Comment: @josh  Ok!!!Understood. Thank you very much

Comment: Why not write it as Mathematica expression and then use TeXForm? I do not know really know what the issue here where you say **I am trying to write the following function via latex** ?   Why write Latex directly when Mathematica can generate it for you? Or do you mean you had this Latex from some where else and wanted to convert it to Mathematica expression?

Comment: @Nasser:  Believe OP wishes to latex-format the case or array expression in a notebook cell such as a Display Formula cell using for example Insert/Inline Tex input into a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replying to comment:

> Believe OP wishes to latex-format the case or array expression in a
> notebook cell such as a Display Formula cell using for example
> Insert/Inline Tex input into a cell

In this case, why not use this:

```
u[x_,t_]:=Piecewise[{{x^2/2+(t-x),0<x<t},{x t-t^2/2+Sin[x-t],x>t>0}}]
tex=TeXForm[u[x,t]];
latex=MaTeX[tex,Magnification->2];
CellPrint[TextCell[Row[{"my formula is ",latex}],"Text"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
CellPrint[TextCell[Row[{"The latex for the above is\n",tex}],"Text"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I still not sure what the problem is. But if they have input as Latex and want to convert that to Mathematica Expression, (in this case to `Piecewise`) then that is different issue.

Not all Latex can be converted back to the original Mathematica expression which generated the Latex (may be it should?). There are limitations.

```
 ToExpression[ToString@tex,TeXForm]
```

[image]

Comment: Bit of overhead configuring MaTeX and pointing it to GhostScript and pdfLatex.exe if OP is interested in this approach.   Here's an improvement if I'm interpreting what OP wants:  It centers it and includes the "u(x,t)=" prefix: `tex = TeXForm[
   HoldForm@(Piecewise[{{x^2/2 + (t - x), 
        0 < x < t}, {x t - t^2/2 + Sin[x - t], x > t > 0}}])];
newTex = "u(x,t)=" <> ToString@tex;
latex = MaTeX[newTex, Magnification -> 1.5];
CellPrint[TextCell[Row[{latex}], TextAlignment -> Center]]`

Comment: Thank you very much both of you for your responses. I have tried the format I have used in Overleaf. That does not work. Yours is pretty handy,

Answer (score 2):

```
u[x_, t_] := 
    Which[0 < x < t, x^2/2 + (t - x), 
          x > t > 0, x t - t^2/2 + Sin[x - t]]

Plot3D[u[x, t],
 {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]